# rewriting js code from a GUI to use in webapp

Tags: javascript

I need a function to calculate an amount of frames in the user input. I have some code from a Electron GUI that does the job, but i'm unsure how to do it in my HTML. I want it to grab the input from `#id_desiredFrames` in the html and then calculate the amount of total frames from that.

Code that needs to be rewritten:

```
 * @example 
 * "55;58-60,2" -> 55,58,60     -> 3 Frames
 * "55;58-60"   -> 55,58,59,60  -> 4 Frames
 */
function calculateFrameAmount(_frame){
    const notationArray = _frame.match(/(\d+)(-)?(\d+)?(\,\d)?/g)
    const calculateNotation = item => {

        if (!isNaN(item))
            return 1

        if (item.includes(",")) {
            [item, diff] = item.split(",");
        }

        const splitItem = item.split("-")
        return Math.floor((Math.max(...splitItem) - Math.min(...splitItem)) / diff) + 1
    }

    let diff = 1;

    return notationArray
        .map(calculateNotation)
        .reduce((total, amount) => total += amount)
}

export default calculateFrameAmount
```

How would I go on about this? I know I can get the value by using `document.getElementById("id_desiredFrames").value;` but how do I add the value into the function??

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: @Sheraff Edited

Comment: Does your web app use ES6?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @CameronTinker . No it does not.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the value to be computed on change, then you can do something like the following:

```
var desiredFrames = document.getElementById("id_desiredFrames");
desiredFrames.onchange = function(e) {
  calculateFrameAmount(e.target.value);
}
```

Additionally, you can run the calculation onkeyup instead if you need it to be real-time:

```
desiredFrames.onkeyup = function(e) {
  calculateFrameAmount(e.target.value);
}
```

Comment: Your code looks good, but I don't think it computes anything since my web app doesn't support ES6. Would that be correct to assume?

Comment: If you want to use ES6 code as-is on older browsers (Internet Explorer 11 for instance), then you will need some sort of transpiling to ES5. I would look at WebPack with Babel. Otherwise, you'll need to convert the code manually from ES6 to ES5.